# websocket server for android, java

Tags: java, android, websocket

I am building a simple websocket server for Android. (let us, say 3.2 - I tried some earlier Android versions with the same result). Before trying the code on Android, I tested it under Java SE on Windows, Linux. It worked OK with Chrome and  Firefox .
However on Android it does not work. Please see the comments in code.

In short:

1. I successfully pass handshaking and browser confirms that connection is OK.
2. I happily receive all the messages from the browser via Websocket
3. I cannot send anything: It just does not get to the javascript callback.
   After some retries (sometimes immediately) the browser closes websocket.

Here is the code:

```
//BufferedOutput myout=new BufferedOutput(mysocket.getOutputStream()));

//myout was successfully used for handshaking before

String msg=”I want to send this”;

try {

  myout.write(129);//129=0x81); text frame 0x81=129
  int payloadlen=msg.length();
  myout.write(payloadlen);
  byte[] bts=msg.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
  myout.write(bts,0,payloadlen);
  myout.flush();//after this command client Browser closes websocket
                //firefox also gives error 
}
catch(IOException ee)
 {
 System.out.println("Error sending websocket message"+ee);
 try{myclose();}catch(IOException eio){}
 }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running this code? Inside an Activity or in a Service.

Notice that if you need to create your one customized Web Server and need to run it on Android you should implement it as a Service running on it own thread.

If you are running it on an Activity depending of the android version, the main thread should not (or can not, depending of the android version) perform I/O operation on the main thread.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it both inside Activity and inside service with the same results. In both cases the code is not running in the main thread. I do have my customized Web Server, which responds to the handshake. The handshake is successful and I can use the same connection to receive text messages (via websocket) from Web Browser (Firefox/Chrome). However I cannot send anything. It looks like my sending somehow signals to web browser to close the connection. It does not happen when I run the code under Sun Java (Windows/Linux).

Comment: And more: I just checked with wireshark that in both cases (Sun Java and Android) my server sends the SAME packets. Mystery.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The reason was that in case of Android, I was sending something BEFORE via the SAME connection. And this "something", though was wrong, somehow did not produce any error in Chrome/Firefox.  It took me two days and byte-to-byte comparison Wireshark results for both cases: my Sun Java Websocket Server and my Android Websocket Server.